# Rebroadcasting data from Vb.Net socket listener to another socket

Tags: vb.net, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

I've got a VB.Net project working that connects to a remote IP/port and receives a continuous string of data from it.  It does this by receiving a byte at a time and assembling it into a string until the EOL character is received, then it currently writes the completed line out to a file.  This is run using a background worker so that it doesn't block the UI of my application.

I'd like to extend it so that the line of data received is pushed to a remote machine via another socket as soon as the EOL character is received.  I've implemented the same basic code as my listening socket to do this and it works but hangs after a random amount of time.

I suspect that there's a problem with the data send completing before the next line of data is sent so I *think* I may need to use an asynchronous socket.

Is this likely to be the best approach ?  If so, should this go on a separate background thread of its own or stay on the current background thread ?

Here's the code that I use to set up the connection to the remote server that I want to send data to:

```
' Create socket to server process
Dim serverSocket As New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient()
Dim serverStream As NetworkStream = Nothing

' Declare buffer for messages sent to server
Dim serverBuffer As Byte()

' Connect to remote server
serverSocket.Connect(serverIp, serverPort)
' Tie server stream to socket
serverStream = serverSocket.GetStream()
```

And this is how I'm actually sending the line of data:

```
' Send line to remote server
serverBuffer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(line)
serverStream.Write(serverBuffer, 0, serverBuffer.Length)
```

It all seems to make sense but Googling around suggests that I should use the .BeginWrite method but that then requires callbacks to be defined and I can't see what purpose they would serve.

Comment: `I suspect that there's a problem with the data send completing before the next line of data is sent so I think I may need to use an asynchronous socket.` - Could you elaborate that? How does the server receive data? Is the server built by you? Also I don't see how sending it asynchronously would help...

Comment: I don't know how the receiver receives data as it's not built by me.  However I can do exactly the same as what I'm doing now in PHP and there is no problem which made me think that it was a VB-specific issue at my end.  Unfortunately there are no error messages shown, the data on the server just disappears which makes detecting the problem and automatically reconnecting tricky

Comment: To me it seems that the server does not want to receive data multiple times. It's hard to tell overall since the code you've shared doesn't indicate anything that should cause a problem, thus your problem is probably related to the method you communicate with the server rather than how you utilize the .NET classes.

Comment: There's not much else to show I'm afraid.  The line of data sent is in the correct format and the remote server just sits there listening for that data.  I have multiple instances of it running for days at a time listening for data in exactly the same format without issue.  I'll carry on digging into my code to see if there's a spurious character getting through.  Thanks for your help